# Limiting a string to to 256 bytes

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I currently have:

```
$payload = array();
$payload['aps']['badge'] = 1;
$payload['aps']['alert'] = html_entity_decode($title);
$payload['aps']['sound'] = "default";
```

But:

> The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is **256 bytes**;
>   Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds
>   this limit.

`$title` (is mainly english, not many special chars) is quite often larger than 256 chars. What should I do to check and limit/remove extra chars? `strlen`?

Comment: PHP string are kind of char arrays. IIRC a char is 1 byte long, so yeah: check with strlen if the string is larger than 256 chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either check with strlen if the title is bigger than 256, or just cut it.
`$title = substr($title, 0, 256);`

Comment: Hm...the total payload actually has be 256 bytes, but strlen won't work on array, right?

Comment: Well I think you will send that array by json? You can calculate the total length of all array values like: `$len = strlen($payload['aps']['alert']) + strlen($payload['aps']['sound']) + ... ;` .Check if its length exceeds 256, and if it does trim the title or the values that can be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

As it's described, the question is about length in bytes so substr is not the right method. I think that `mb_strcut` method should be used instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php